# XDMP-RANGEINDEX Error for decimal properties value saved via the Java API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

For each XML we store in MarkLogic we store calculated values in the document's associated properties.  One of these values is a potentially large decimal value. Which is causing an exception because the Marklogic Java API is formatting the number in the XML it sends to the MarkLogic server in a way that the MarkLogic server doesn’t like.

We have a Range Element Index set up on a “TotalObligatedAmount” element that we store in the properties:

The Java code below reproduces the issues we are seeing:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
 
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
 
import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClient;
import com.marklogic.client.document.XMLDocumentManager;
import com.marklogic.client.io.DOMHandle;
import com.marklogic.client.io.DocumentMetadataHandle;
 
@Component
public class LoadTester {
 
  private final XMLDocumentManager mgr;
  
  public LoadTester(DatabaseClient client) {
    this.mgr = client.newXMLDocumentManager();
  }
 
  public void loadTest() throws Exception {
    String uri = "testDocument.xml";
    DOMHandle handle = new DOMHandle();
    String xml = "<test><value>Hello World</value></test>";
    Document doc = handle.getFactory().newDocumentBuilder()
                   .parse(IOUtils.toInputStream(xml, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    DocumentMetadataHandle metadataHandle = new DocumentMetadataHandle();
    metadataHandle.withProperty("TotalObligatedAmount",Double.valueOf(18912626.00));
    handle.set(doc);
    mgr.write(mgr.newDescriptor(uri), metadataHandle, handle);
  }
}
```

This results in the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: write failed: Bad Request. Server Message: XDMP-RANGEINDEX: Range index error: decimal xdmp:document-properties("testDocument.xml")/prop:properties/TotalObligatedAmount: XDMP-LEXVAL: Invalid lexical value "1.8912626E7"
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.putPostDocumentImpl(OkHttpServices.java:1697)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.putDocument(OkHttpServices.java:1344)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.write(DocumentManagerImpl.java:940)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.write(DocumentManagerImpl.java:888)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.write(DocumentManagerImpl.java:827)
```

The properties data XML that the Java API is generating and sending to the server is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<rapi:metadata xmlns:rapi="http://marklogic.com/rest-api"
    xmlns:prop="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <prop:properties>
        <TotalObligatedAmount xsi:type="xs:double">1.8912626E7</TotalObligatedAmount>
    </prop:properties>
</rapi:metadata>
```

When serializing the properties to XML the decimal value of 18,912,626.00 is being turned into the string 1.8912626E7 and the MarkLogic server is rejecting that string.

I was able to step through the code to find out how the double gets converted to a string. The `com.marklogic.client.impl.ValueConverter` does the conversion and it uses the `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDouble()` method to convert the Double to the “1.8912626E7” String (ultimately using the String.valueOf(doubleValue) method.

Does anyone know how I can get around this?  Is there a change I need to make on the server or a way to configure the Java API?

I'm using version 5.2.0 of the Java API and version 10.0-8.1 of the MarkLogic server.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out if you add the property as a BigDecimal instead of a Double it gets serialized correctly.

Changing `metadataHandle.withProperty("TotalObligatedAmount",Double.valueOf(18912626.00));`
to
`metadataHandle.withProperty("TotalObligatedAmount",new BigDecimal(18912626.00));`
was enough to make the code work.

Comment: I would have expected the value as exponent to still insert and not throw the XDMP-RANGEINDEX error though. I was testing locally on MarkLogic 10.0-8.3 and didn't get an error when I inserted exponent values in an XML doc with a range index as xs:double.